# add custom conditions in highchart configuration

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm wondering if there is a way to add if condition in chart definition. I'm creating MACD in the chart for which this part is definitely needed.

```
yAxis : [{
         ordinal: false,
         height:280,
        }, {

         title: {
            text: 'MACD'
            },
        top: 360,
        height: 87,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 1
       }]
```

Now I have a requirement where if window loads then do not show macd marker line.It should be shown when the , macd indicator is added and deleted when removed.So, is there any way to add if condition like

```
yAxis : [{
             ordinal: false,
             height:280,
            }, {
            if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
            {                               
              title: {
                text: 'MACD'
                },
              top: 360,
              height: 87,
              offset: 0,
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
yAxis: [{
    ordinal: false,
    height: 280,
}, (document.getElementById('button').clicked ? {
    title: {
        text: 'MACD'
    },
    top: 360,
    height: 87,
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 1
} : {})]
```

Comment: its showing syntax error near `}, (document.getElementById('button').clicked ? : {`

Comment: See updated answer - I have an extra `:` sign, now it's removed. Note: it add new yAxis, but it's just empty one, or you can use other options like disabling title etc.